# Display some popup, when i mousenter to element. Pure CSS

Tags: html, css, popup

I have some problem. For example, i have some div elem, with img inside. I need display another div, when mouse hover to element. It ease to do using js\jquery. But i need todo this in pure html\css

For example simple code `http://jsfiddle.net/3bTcF/`

I saw example in `http://krisha.kz/`. When mouse enter to photo, displays more content.

Can some body help me, and give an idea, how ещ вщ ше

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/3bTcF/1/ I've only added the display attributes to the CSS.

```
.caption:hover>.caption-popup {
    display:block;
}

.caption-popup{
    position: absolute;
    display:none;
}
```